# LINQ to Entities Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object' when using Distinct()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using LINQ to Entities to get a list,

This is a very simple version of the query I'm using:

```cs
from ItemLine in ItemLines
from CheckHistory in ChecksHistories
where CheckHistory.CurrentItemLineAutoKey == ItemLine.ItemLineAutoKey
select new 
{
    Name = (from a in ItemLineInfo
        where a.InfoAutoKey == (from b in ItemLines
            where CheckHistory.OriginalItemLineAutoKey == b.ItemLineAutoKey
            select b.InfoAutoKey).FirstOrDefault()
        select a.TypeID).Any(S=> types.Contains(S)) ? "FirstName" : "SecondName"
}
```

And it works great, UNTIL I add .Distinct() to the end of the query, then I get the error:

`Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'`

What could be the issue in this?

Comment: But where do you add `Distinct()`?

Comment: `var Query = (queryHere).Distinct()`

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Does your simple query have the same error with `Distinct`? What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: What exactly is `types` here? That's the only place I could conceivably see that causing the error. What is the _full_ stack trace for that error? The types of your entities? etc

Comment: @NetMage Yes, it does. I pointed out I'm also using LINQ to Entities, using EF6 with SQL.

@JeffMercado `types` is an array of strings in this case.

Comment: @potatomolato Can you provide a small sample of data?